# What does 'pulse' in STM32CUBE in PWM generation

Tags: pwm, embedded, stm32cubemx

I would like to know what 'pulse(16 bits value )' for is it Ton of the PWM signal

[image]

Comment: So it is not explained in the manual?

Comment: @Justme I am not sure pulse mode or Ton of the signal

Comment: It's in the documentation. Also, why would they use a 16-bit value to set "pulse mode"?

Answer (score 3):

That controls the width of the PWM pulse according to the formula:

```
pulse_length = ((TIM_Period + 1) * DutyCycle) / 100 - 1
```

You use that to calculate the desired duty cycle.

While you can set that in STM32CUBE IDE, you most often set it from your program as you vary the PWM for whatever you are doing at the time.

Usually you will set it to 0 in the IDE as an initial value so whatever is on the PWM line won't start on its own.